# stripe payment refund receipt url

Tags: stripe-payments

when I am calling stripe refund API, I am getting bellow data after successful refund. I need to send receipt of this transaction to user.

from stripe documentation:
**receipt_number** is the transaction number that appears on email receipts sent for this refund.

I am getting receipt_number null.

```
 const refund = await stripe.refunds.create({
        charge: payment.strip.chargeId,
        amount: refundAmount * 100,
      });

response: 

{
  "id": "re_3K0N3qGRxQkYXSuu2S7aM0jl",
  "object": "refund",
  "amount": 4000,
  "balance_transaction": "txn_3K0N3qGRxQkYXSuu2kjkWM1p",
  "charge": "ch_3K0N3qGRxQkYXSuu2BqK8PLo",
  "created": 1638005716,
  "currency": "usd",
  "metadata": {},
  "payment_intent": "pi_3K0N3qGRxQkYXSuu2t1S1xl5",
  "reason": null,
  "receipt_number": null,
  "source_transfer_reversal": null,
  "status": "succeeded",
  "transfer_reversal": null
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple reasons for a receipt not being sent. You would want to double check:

1. The Customer in the original Charge should have an email address
2. You should turn on your [Refund Receipt in Dashboard as mentioned here](https://stripe.com/docs/receipts#refund-receipts)
3. In Test mode Stripe does not automatically send Receipt email. They only send in Live mode

When all conditions are met, then Stripe will send an email and you would have that receipt_number value